# jaxb conversion unmarshalling find which objects are present in xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML like

```
<Add>
    <A someAttr="value">
</ADD>
<ADD>
    <F someAttr="value">
<ADD/>
<CHANGE>
    <D someAttr="value">
</CHANGE>
```

In ADD and CHANGE Types there is only one tag from A to Z. When I unmarshal using JAXB I get the objects properly but I do not know which one is present unless I check all 26 for null. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: It depends. Do the values have useful default-values? Then you could use those if the tag is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an `Unmarshaller.Listener` and set in on the `Unmarshaller`.  This object will be called for each object that is unmarshalled.  You could add the logic you need here.

Comment: Thanks Blaise Doughan. Ill try using listener.